# Force directed graph:Accessing nodes with certain links

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a force directed graph. on changing the values of a combobox, the following code works:

```
$(function() {    
       $('#category').change(function(){
                var current_year = $(this).val();

                link.data(_links).transition().duration(2000).style("opacity", function(d)         {
                        if (d.type == current_year){
                                return "1";
                            }
                            else{
                                return "0";
                            }
                         });
                     });
```

Along with updating the links, I also want to change the opacity of the nodes, if nodes have no visible edges, their opacity should also change to 0. How can I select the nodes whose all edges have opacity 0?

Comment: In the else statement try like this? `d3.select(this).attr("class", "opactiy-0")`? Then select those elements using that class.

Comment: How does this affect the nodes? I want the nodes with all invisible edges to become invisible.

Comment: Can you instead provide a fiddle?